# CSS keyframes animation using "left" as movement doesn't work in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am currently learning web design from scratch and have begun attempting animations, specifically @keyframes. I was initially designing whilst just using chrome and made the foolish assumption that this would work across all browsers. After testing a more complex animation that worked in chrome, opera and firefox, I tried Internet Explorer/Edge and the opacity animation worked but the method I used for translation didn't. I am just editing the left value of a list item in order to "move" the list items across.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-gb">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8; width=device_width;" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Homepage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS\index\indexTesting.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<!--Navigation Bar-->
<div id="navigationBar">
    <ul>
        <li id="liAbout"><a>About</a></li>
        <li id="liPortfolio"><a>Portfolio</a></li>
        <li id="liServices"><a>Services</a></li>
        <li id="liContact"><a>Contact</a></li>
        <li id="liBlog"><a>Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--Navigation Bar-->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS with keyframe animation at the start:

```
@keyframes listEntranceAnimation{
    0%{
        left:50%;
    }
    100%{
        left:0;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes listEntranceAnimation{
    0%{
        left:50%;
    }
    100%{
        left:0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes listEntranceAnimation{
    0%{
        left:50%;
    }
    100%{
        left:0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes listEntranceAnimation{
    0%{
        left:50%;
    }
    100%{
        left:0;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes listEntranceAnimation{
    0%{
        left:50%;
    }
    100%{
        left:0;
    }
}
html, body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    background-color:#0f0f0f;
}
#navigationBar{
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
}

#navigationBar ul{
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style-type:none;
    display:table;
    width:49.8%;
    left:50%;
    height:5%;
    top:6px;

}
#navigationBar li{
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:8px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:20%;
    -webkit-animation:listEntranceAnimation 4s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
    -o-animation:listEntranceAnimation 4s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
    -moz-animation:listEntranceAnimation 4s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
    animation:listEntranceAnimation 4s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
    -ms-animation:listEntranceAnimation 4s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
}
#navigationBar li a{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:100;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

I am also linking to a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7w63z31v/) so you can see the visual difference for the intended effect and the absence of effect within internet explorer. I attempted to change the meta tag to 
`http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"` based on a separate post but this also didn't work. I assume it is an issue due to me misunderstanding how the browser deals with "left".

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7w63z31v/5/) is the solution:

```
#navigationBar ul{
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style-type:none;
    display:table;
    width:49.8%;
    height:5%;
    top:6px;
    float: right;
    -webkit-animation:listEntranceAnimation 4s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
    -o-animation:listEntranceAnimation 4s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
    -moz-animation:listEntranceAnimation 4s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
    animation:listEntranceAnimation 4s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
    -ms-animation:listEntranceAnimation 4s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

#navigationBar li{
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:8px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:20%;
}
```

It works in Edge and IE. 
To `#navigationBar ul` I have added `float: right;` and deleted `left: 50%;`; and moved your animation code from  `#navigationBar li` to `#navigationBar ul`

Answer (score 0):

```css
@keyframes listEntranceAnimation{
 0%{
  left:50%;
 }
 100%{
  left:0;
 }
}
@-o-keyframes listEntranceAnimation{
 0%{
  left:50%;
 }
 100%{
  left:0;
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes listEntranceAnimation{
 0%{
  left:50%;
 }
 100%{
  left:0;
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes listEntranceAnimation{
 0%{
  left:50%;
 }
 100%{
  left:0;
 }
}
@-ms-keyframes listEntranceAnimation{
 0%{
  left:50%;
 }
 100%{
  left:0;
 }
}
html, body{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:0;
 background-color:#0f0f0f;
}
#navigationBar{
 position:relative;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 width:100%;
}

#navigationBar ul{
 position:relative;
 //margin:0;
 padding:0;
 overflow:hidden;
 list-style-type:none;
 display:table;
 width:49.8%;
 //left:50%;
 height:5%;
 top:6px;
  float: right;
   -webkit-animation:listEntranceAnimation 4s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
 -o-animation:listEntranceAnimation 4s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
 -moz-animation:listEntranceAnimation 4s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
 animation:listEntranceAnimation 4s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
 -ms-animation:listEntranceAnimation 4s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
 
}
#navigationBar li{
 position:relative;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:8px;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
 width:20%;

}
#navigationBar li a{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 z-index:100;
 color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<title>Homepage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS\index\indexTesting.css"/>

<body>
<!--Navigation Bar-->
<div id="navigationBar">
 <ul>
  <li id="liAbout"><a>About</a></li>
  <li id="liPortfolio"><a>Portfolio</a></li>
  <li id="liServices"><a>Services</a></li>
  <li id="liContact"><a>Contact</a></li>
  <li id="liBlog"><a>Blog</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<!--Navigation Bar-->
</body>
</html>
```